# How to add a function to a Button class which will be executed when clicked in Processing/java

Tags: java, processing

I made a class called Button;
In the constructor I draw a button.
However I want to give a class name for instance a MainMenu or Settings to that constructor which will be executed when clicked on the button. What's the proper way to program this in Java.

It's for a school assignment

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If this is for a school assignment, you are supposed to figure this out yourself.

Comment: Questions like this one are completely incomprehensible to others (or at least to me) without providing some snippet of source code...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an actionListener, either in the "main" method, or a constructor.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(100,100);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        f.add(button);
        f.addActionListener (new ActionListener () { //<---this is the important part
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //do whatever you need to do here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be inspired be [this processing tutorial](http://processing.org/examples/button.html) 
or you should use some libraries for creating menu with buttons [like controlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/)